# Unable to click any link in the web page

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver to automate a web page. My selenium code is not identifying the link. I am getting the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/font/font/b/a[2]"}   (Session
>   info: chrome=44.0.2403.89)

This is the code i am using .

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
         driver.get("url");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font/font/b/a[2]")).click();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share you HTML of your link as well??

Comment: <a href="DutOff.do_ChooseCase" target="_top">Duty Office</a>

Comment: Ok I have already provided it as an answer, try it and let me know if nay problem.:)

Comment: Try this "//body/font/font/b/a[2]"

Comment: can you provide which domain and http page you testing so i can validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There are may be following reasons :-

- May you are locating with incorrect `xpath`, So you need to share HTML for better locator solution.
- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and clickable as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Duty Office")));
  el.click();
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));
  //Now find the element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Duty Office")));
  el.click();

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, it did the trick. But now after the link is clicked am getting one more error                                                                            Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: no element reference returned by script
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.89)

Comment: @Elaine this occur due to stale of element. You can store Web Element ans perform action till page has not change. Once page has been changed selenium delete the reference of element from their case, in this case you need to find element again...:)

Comment: ohh ok. But if the next page(Clicking on the link is navigated to new page) has the same problem then can i use the wait statement i already used or do i need to create a new wait statement again? in the new page i tried finding a new element but am getting the same problem as i got in the first place

Comment: @Elaine no need to create new wait object again. Just use already created wait object with same  expected conditions...:)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the trouble. As i mentioned earlier navigating to the new page is not recognising the frame now. only first frame is been recognised and clicked but not the next one.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("left"));
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Duty Office")));
el.click(); here i am navigated to new page where i need to click one more link, so i ahve written same code 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("right"));
WebElement el1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Case/CDD")));
el1.click();

Comment: @Elaine once you switched any frame, then you need to switch back from that frame using `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` before switching to next frame.. try it

Comment: @Elaine I updated it in the answer as well in the last point.. see it. you need to do as `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("left")); WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Duty Office"))); el.click(); driver.switchTo().defaultContent();wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("right")); WebElement el1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Case/CDD"‌​))); el1.click();`

Comment: @Elaine Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer as well, if it helped..:)

Comment: @Elaine You welcome.. Please accept the answer as well if it helped. have a look here how to accept correct answer..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Is it the same approach for dropdowns? how do we select a dropdown value

Comment: can you please let me know how to handle dropdons in this situation?

Comment: @Elaine I'm sorry but this I'm not able to give you answer.. please ask another question regarding this..:)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible situation

1) you might type wrong url

2) your expected element xpath is wrong.

please validate your xpath with

this tolol : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("Valid url");

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("your valid XPATH")).click();

  driver.close();
 }
```

Comment: I have given the correct url, i am able to go the url but not able to click any link or any button or enter data in text box in the page.

Comment: have you try to validate you Xpath with provided plugin

Comment: Yeah i have validated

Comment: still facing issue ??